# How to get from os.system the same exit code that would be stored in $? running the command from terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, os.system, python-os

running with os.system() a bash command like `timeout -s 9 10 <bash command>`, when the `<bash command>` goes in timeout the variable `$?` contains the value 137.

If i run it from python with `os.system("timeout -s 9 10 <bash command>")` the returned value is 9 and, if I use `os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system("timeout -s 9 10 <bash command>"))` is 0.

The question is: it's possible to get the same value that would be stored in `$?` ?

Comment: I also find this behavior confusing, but it's generally recommended to use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`

Comment: On python/Debian, `os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system("timeout -s 9 1 sleep 2"))` gives 137